# I cannot connect to MySQL database from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database. I can connect to the database from phpMyAdmin using the root user. Then I have created a new user. And granted it all privileges. But I cannot login to phpMyAdmin using that new user.

**The commands I have used**

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '​abc@123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'%' with grant option;
flush privileges;
```

**Expected Behaviour:** I should be able to login into phpMyAdmin.

I am getting the following error.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
> 'new_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between '%' and 'localhost'.

In MySQL, '%' matches any TCP/IP host. Your error message indicates that you're connecting via socket connection ('localhost' is always socket). In order to allow user access from both TCP and socket connections, you'll have to create two users, one for each host type. If you know you don't need the TCP user, you can save yourself some hassle (and increase security to some degree) by only having the 'socket' user.